# modoboa on ubuntu 20.04 : supervisord exited: policyd (exit status 1; not expected)

Tags: supervisord

New modoboa 2.o  install on ubuntu 20.04 doesnt work and giving error in syslog.

```
supervisord  exited: policyd (exit status 1; not expected)
```

Tried everything no clue

Answer (score 0):

you have to check logs /var/log/supervisor/policyd-stdout---supervisor

if you see  error like :

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'asgiref'
```

you must upgrade asgiref:

```
su - modoboa

source env/bin/activate      
pip install asgiref
```